# Can't install Poedit on Linux Mint

Tags: installation, linux-mint, poedit

When I type:

```
sudo apt-get install poedit
```

I get this error:

> Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
>
> Creando árbol de dependencias
>
> Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
>
> Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes extras:
>
> libdb5.1++
>
> Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
>
> libdb5.1++ poedit
>
> 0 actualizados, 2 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 1 no actualizados.
>
> Se necesita descargar 738 kB/1.581 kB de archivos.
>
> Se utilizarán 5.192 kB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
>
> ¿Desea continuar [S/n]? s
>
> AVISO: ¡No se han podido autenticar los siguientes paquetes!
>
> libdb5.1++ poedit
>
> ¿Instalar estos paquetes sin verificación [s/N]? s
>
> Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libdb5.1++ amd64 5.1.29-5ubuntu8
>
> Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libdb5.1++ amd64 5.1.29-5ubuntu8
>     404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
>
> Imposible obtener http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/db/libdb5.1++_5.1.29-5ubuntu8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
>
> E: No se pudieron obtener algunos archivos, ¿quizás deba ejecutar «apt-get update» o deba intentarlo de nuevo con --fix-missing?

Of course, I've tried with `sudo apt-get update` and then tried again with `--fix-missing`, but I'm getting the same error.

I've also tried downloading the package from [Poedit](http://poedit.net/download), and then doing:

```
./configure
```

but I'm getting this error:

> checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>
> checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>
> checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
>
> checking whether build environment is sane... yes
>
> checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
>
> checking for gawk... gawk
>
> checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
>
> checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
>
> checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
>
> checking for install location... /usr/local
>
> checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
>
> checking whether ln -s works... yes
>
> checking for ranlib... ranlib
>
> checking for gcc... gcc
>
> checking whether the C compiler works... yes
>
> checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
>
> checking for suffix of executables...
>
> checking whether we are cross compiling... no
>
> checking for suffix of object files... o
>
> checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
>
> checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
>
> checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
>
> checking for style of include used by make... GNU
>
> checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
>
> checking for g++... g++
>
> checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
>
> checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
>
> checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
>
> checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
>
> checking whether g++ supports C++11 features by default... no
>
> checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=gnu++11... yes
>
> checking for wx-config... no
>
> configure: error: 
>          Please check that wx-config is in path, the directory
>           where wxWidgets libraries are installed (returned by
>           'wx-config --unicode --libs' command) is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or
>           equivalent variable and wxWidgets is version 2.8.0 or above,
>           with Unicode build available.

Any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: I'd start by making sure that wxWidgets is installed for the compile. as for the apt-get issue, I can't read spanish, but it kinda looks like a repository couldn't be found. this is not uncommon, and usually waiting a few hours or a day will correct issues with failure to connect to specific repositories.

Comment: I would rather go with [official installation manual](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/WxWidgets30Binaries#toc2) than with Berkley Database lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've achieved with these two steps:

#### 1. Download and install `libdb5.1++` from [archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/db/libdb5.1++_5.1.29-7_amd64.deb](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/db/libdb5.1++_5.1.29-7_amd64.deb)

#### 2. Then, `sudo apt-get install poedit`

And that's all.

Comment: I really thought I had to compile from source... Thanks for this!! On ubuntu 16 I only had to run the apt-get command.